# Chromedriver incompatibility that occurred with the last Chrome update on 15.12.2023

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-java

Dec 17, 2023 5:46:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch

WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 120, returning the closest version; found: 119; Please update to a Selenium version that supports CDP version 120

I get this error

I downloaded the latest version of chromedriver from the selenium page and updated it to selenium Java 4.15.0 on the POM.xml page.

Answer (score 2):

Try change dependency in pom.xml file to the latest Selenium Java version  4.16.1

```
<version>4.16.1</version>
```